# aligned calloc, visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

There is a function called `_aligned_malloc` which can allocate aligned memory. Is there a similar function for `calloc`? I want to align and initialize it to zero. I am using visual studio 2010

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can roll your own pretty easily:

```
void *_aligned_calloc(size_t nelem, size_t elsize, size_t alignment)
{
    // Watch out for overflow
    if(elsize == 0 || nelem >= SIZE_T_MAX/elsize)
        return NULL;

    size_t size = nelem * elsize;
    void *memory = _aligned_malloc(size, alignment);
    if(memory != NULL)
        memset(memory, 0, size);
    return memory;
}
```

Comment: This looses the main benefit of calloc which is that it can ask the OS for already zeroed-out memory pages, thus avoiding costly memsets. Linux does that at least.